# Update specific value from specific row with pandas python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Inside of my tag_data.csv file I want to change the  column for “Posts”  value from “4532” to “1234”  in the the row that contains “metal “

My csv file looks like this:

```
    Tag    Posts
0 plastic   2456
0 paper     3449
0 metal     4532
0 other     8722
```

The output should be the file updated and saved to look like this:

```
    Tag    Posts
0 plastic   2456
0 paper     3449
0 metal     1234
0 other     8722
```

This is what I’ve been trying:

```
read_csv = pd.read_csv(‘tag_data.csv’)

read_csv.loc[read_csv.Tag == ‘metal’, ‘Posts’], [‘Posts’] = 123.to_csv(‘tag_data.csv’)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do too much in one line, this should do the value replacement:

```
read_csv.loc[(read_csv["Tag"]=="metal"), "Posts"] = 1234
```

Alternatively, you can use `replace` with a dictionary of values:

```
read_csv["Posts"] = read_csv["Posts"].replace({4532: 1234})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but for what ever reason the file does not get changed even though I can print the correct value